# I want to add More than 1 table in Config.xml file of Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.4, magento-1.6, magento

I have added two tables in my Magento Config.xml file. please tell me is it a correct way to add multiple table in magento.

```
               <tiger_mysql4>
         <class>Scott_Tiger_Model_Mysql4</class>
         <entities>
             <tiger>
               <table>shop_data</table>
                </tiger>
                              <tiger>
                               <table>Cust_college</table>
                                </tiger>
          </entities>
    </tiger_mysql4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tiger_mysql4>
     <class>Scott_Tiger_Model_Mysql4</class>
     <entities>
         <tiger_shop>
              <table>shop_data</table>
         </tiger_shop>
         <tiger_cust>
              <table>Cust_college</table>
         </tiger_cust>
     </entities>
</tiger_mysql4>
```

Model name should be unique. In your case it was `tiger` two times.